# bioptools compilation problem (make)

Tags: 20.04, compiling, gcc

[ubuntu 20.04.3]

Im trying to install program (https://github.com/ACRMGroup/bioptools) and have this error when im run make (following the installation instructions)

```
(base) marcin@marcin-Lenovo-ideapad-Y700-15ISK:~/bioptools-1.9/src$ makeenter code here
(cd libsrc/bioplib/src; make)
make[1]: enter the catalogue '/home/marcin/bioptools-1.9/src/libsrc/bioplib/src'

[...]

gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o AddNTerHs.o -c AddNTerHs.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o ApMatPDB.o -c ApMatPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o AppendPDB.o -c AppendPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o AtomNameMatch.o -c AtomNameMatch.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o CalcCellTrans.o -c CalcCellTrans.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o CalcChiPDB.o -c CalcChiPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o CalcCterCoords.o -c CalcCterCoords.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o CalcRMSPDB.o -c CalcRMSPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o CalcTetraHCoords.o -c CalcTetraHCoords.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o CopyPDB.o -c CopyPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o CopyPDBCoords.o -c CopyPDBCoords.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o DNAtoAA.o -c DNAtoAA.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o DupePDB.o -c DupePDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o ExtractZonePDB.o -c ExtractZonePDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o FNam2PDB.o -c FNam2PDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o FindAtomInRes.o -c FindAtomInRes.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o FindNextChainPDB.o -c FindNextChainPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o FindNextResidue.o -c FindNextResidue.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o FindResidue.o -c FindResidue.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o FindResidueSpec.o -c FindResidueSpec.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o FindZonePDB.o -c FindZonePDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o FitCaCbPDB.o -c FitCaCbPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o FitCaPDB.o -c FitCaPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o FitPDB.o -c FitPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o FixCterPDB.o -c FixCterPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o GetCGPDB.o -c GetCGPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o GetCofGPDBRange.o -c GetCofGPDBRange.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o GetCofGPDBSCRange.o -c GetCofGPDBSCRange.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o GetCrystPDB.o -c GetCrystPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o GetPDBByN.o -c GetPDBByN.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o GetPDBChainLabels.o -c GetPDBChainLabels.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o GetPDBCoor.o -c GetPDBCoor.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o HAddPDB.o -c HAddPDB.c
HAddPDB.c: In function ‘blOpenPGPFile’:
HAddPDB.c:1388:31: warning: ‘sprintf’ may write a terminating nul past the end of the destination [-Wformat-overflow=]
 1388 |          sprintf(buffer,"%s/%s",datadir,basename);
      |                               ^
HAddPDB.c:1388:10: note: ‘sprintf’ output 2 or more bytes (assuming 161) into a destination of size 160
 1388 |          sprintf(buffer,"%s/%s",datadir,basename);
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o InPDBZone.o -c InPDBZone.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o InPDBZoneSpec.o -c InPDBZoneSpec.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o IndexPDB.o -c IndexPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o KillPDB.o -c KillPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o KillSidechain.o -c KillSidechain.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o KnownSeqLen.o -c KnownSeqLen.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o LegalAtomSpec.o -c LegalAtomSpec.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o MovePDB.o -c MovePDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o NumericAlign.o -c NumericAlign.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o OrderPDB.o -c OrderPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o OriginPDB.o -c OriginPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o PDB2Seq.o -c PDB2Seq.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o ParseRes.o -c ParseRes.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o RdSSPDB.o -c RdSSPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o RdSecPDB.o -c RdSecPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o RdSeqPDB.o -c RdSeqPDB.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o ReadCSSR.o -c ReadCSSR.c
gcc -fPIC -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -DGUNZIP_SUPPORT -finline-functions -D XML_SUPPORT -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2 -I/home/marcin/anaconda3/include -o ReadPDB.o -c ReadPDB.c
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:38,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/umachine.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/umachine.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/umachine.h:46,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:38,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ptypes.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ptypes.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ptypes.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/umachine.h:46,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:38,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/platform.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/platform.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/platform.h:24,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ptypes.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/umachine.h:46,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:38,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/uconfig.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/uconfig.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/platform.h:25,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ptypes.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/umachine.h:46,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:38,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/uvernum.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/uvernum.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/umachine.h:379,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:38,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/urename.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/urename.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:39,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/uversion.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/uversion.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:44,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf.h:217,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:44,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf8.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf8.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf.h:218,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:44,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf16.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf16.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf.h:221,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:44,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf_old.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf_old.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf_old.h:150,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf.h:221,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:44,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utf.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h:88,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:52,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:428:9: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wendif-labels]
  428 | #endif  // U_HIDE_DEPRECATED_API
      |         ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:470:9: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wendif-labels]
  470 | #endif  // U_HIDE_DEPRECATED_API
      |         ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:517:9: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wendif-labels]
  517 | #endif  // U_HIDE_DEPRECATED_API
      |         ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:548:9: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wendif-labels]
  548 | #endif  // U_HIDE_DEPRECATED_API
      |         ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:574:9: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wendif-labels]
  574 | #endif  // U_HIDE_DEPRECATED_API
      |         ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:610:9: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wendif-labels]
  610 | #endif  // U_HIDE_DEPRECATED_API
      |         ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:631:9: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wendif-labels]
  631 | #endif  // U_HIDE_DEPRECATED_API
      |         ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:651:9: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wendif-labels]
  651 | #endif  // U_HIDE_DEPRECATED_API
      |         ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/utypes.h:659:9: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wendif-labels]
  659 | #endif  // U_HIDE_DEPRECATED_API
      |         ^
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:53,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/uenum.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/uenum.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/uenum.h:23,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:53,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/localpointer.h:1:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    1 | // Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others.
      | ^
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/localpointer.h:1:1: note: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31,
                 from /home/marcin/anaconda3/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810,
                 from ReadPDB.c:324:
/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/unicode/ucnv.h:952:9: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wendif-labels]
  952 | #endif  // U_HIDE_DEPRECATED_API
      |         ^
make[1]: *** [Makefile:125: ReadPDB.o] error 1
make[1]: exiting from catalogue '/home/marcin/bioptools-1.9/src/libsrc/bioplib/src'
make: *** [Makefile:16: bioplib] error 2
```

Comment: The build process seems to be locating header files under `/home/marcin/anaconda3/include/` instead of the system's `/usr/include` - I'm not sure that's desireable. Perhaps you have some compiler related variables (`CFLAGS` etc. ) in your environment?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks :) I just deactvate conda base env and problem solved!